# In my .Net Standard Library project, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager does not seem to work

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

In my .Net Standard Library Project, 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager does not seem to work.

Even the method Does not get called, which contains the Statement

```
object o = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(_strSectionName);
```

I have Installed the Nuget package 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager version 4.6.0

But if I right click on ConfigurationManager in this statement,

```
object o = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(_strSectionName);
```

It shows me the metadata of version 4.0.2.0, namely

```
Assembly System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
```

where I think the version it should go to is 4.6.0.

Maybe that is causing the problem.

Comment: The assembly version and the package version are not aligned. Check the location of the referenced assembly

Comment: I dont think `ConfigurationManager` is part of the .Net Standard, it is only .Net Framework - but i could be wrong though.

Comment: @FrankNielsen It is part of Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly version is correct, it should be `4.0.2.0`, this is separate from the package version (here `4.6.0`).

This is not the cause of your problem. The next thing to look at is the exception, or the incorrect behaviour.